# Clarification on constructor and __proto__ property

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

I have been reading on the `constructor` and `__proto__` in javascript.I think i understand the basics of the `__proto__` property however I am having a little trouble with the `constrcutor` property. Here is what I understand so far regarding both properties please correct me if I am wrong or add if I missed some point. Every object in javascript has a "hidden" property called `__proto__` which by default points to `Object.prototype`.Now when an instance of an object is created using new.The value of this property is modified and is assigned the object `ConstructorName.prototype`. I am not sure what the default value of `__proto__` is before `new` is called.Now regarding `.constructor` I am a little confused I read [this](http://javascript.info/tutorial/constructor) and so far believe that `constructor` property by default is empty and when new is invoked the `constrcutor` is modified and assigned `ConstructorName.prototype.constructor`. Kindly let me know if I am headed in the right direction .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Every object in javascript has a "hidden" property called `__proto__`

No. The hidden property is called *[[prototype]]*. `.__proto__` is a deprecated getter that accesses it, you should use [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf)

> which by default points to `Object.prototype`.

"default" might be misleading - it depends on how the object is created. For plain object literals, yes, it's `Object.prototype`.

> Now when an instance of an object is created using new. The value of this property is modified and is assigned the object `ConstructorName.prototype`. I am not sure what the default value of `__proto__` is before new is called.

There is no value before that. The object is created with the prototype being set from the very beginning. Before `new` is called, there is no object.

> Now regarding `.constructor` I am a little confused I read this and so far believe that constructor property by default is empty and when new is invoked the constrcutor is modified and assigned `ConstructorName.prototype.constructor`.

No, nothing is assigned anywhere, there is no `.constructor` property on instances. They do *inherit* the property (along with others) from the `.prototype` object.
The `ConstructorName.prototype.constructor` property is created right in the instance where the `ConstructorName` function is created.

Comment: Thanks for the post. You mentioned "Before new is called, there is no object" what I meant to ask in that part of the question is that when we declare a normal object (i.e) `foo = {}` in that case the default `foo.__proto__ = Object.prototype` and once we create an instance by doing  `var f = new foo()` in that case `f.__proto__ = foo.prototype` am i correct ?

Comment: Yes. `foo = {}` is equivalent to `foo = Object.create(Object.prototype)`, and `f = new foo` is equivalent to `f = Object.create(foo.prototype); f.constructor()`

Comment: Ok thanks for clearing that up. One last question you mentioned that "there is no .constructor property on instances. They do inherit the property (along with others) from the .prototype object." . This link http://javascript.info/tutorial/constructor in the first example seems to show that the instance has the property `.constructor` (i.e) `alert( rabbit.constructor == Rabbit ) // true` I am a little confused here. Am i going in to too much detail here ?

Comment: It's not an *own* property (like it would exist when you assigned `rabbit.constructor = …`), it's an *inherited* property. If you change `Rabbit.prototype.constructor`, `rabbit.constructor` would reflect the change. Welcome to the wonderful world of prototypical inheritance!

Comment: so in a sense it is an actual property only that its assignment is automatic and is always `ConstructoName.prototype.constructor` ?

Comment: I would say no, there is no actual property. There is no "automatic assignment", the inheritance happens for *lookup* of the property. If no (own) property exists, it does follow the [[prototype]] chain to find a property with the key. (Also you can *shadow* the inherited one by creating an own property, e.g. by assignment, so that it has a different value than `ConstructoName.prototype.constructor`)

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thanks for clearing that up. Appreciate it